# how to get the linux terminal name

Tags: java, linux, terminal, command

I want to execute a command with the terminal in linux. Now in order to do this I can't hard code cmd like I do windows. How do I get the terminal name programatically as String from java?

```
new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"xfce4-terminal", "--title="+windowTitle, "--hold", "-x", "java", "-jar", decodedPath, "run"}).start();
```

Notice the string "xfce4-terminal". This changes depending on what distribution of linux they have. What reliable way is there to get the terminal exe for java commands. In my opinion it should by System.getProperty("os.terminal") but, that doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you try something more like https://dzone.com/articles/execute-shell-command-java ?

Comment: Any distro can have multiple installed. Maybe have a preferences list including `xterm` as a default

Comment: @FabienMIFSUD I saw that as an option but, that lists too much data I need only the os terminal name and reliably get it.

Comment: @stark do all linux have xterm? I need to open terminal in a new window and execute a command.

Comment: Not guaranteed.

Comment: how do you linux users generate universal shell scripts then? I need it to run in the terminal. I tried the open command but, then in ubuntu it opened it as a text document with my program. Is there a command where I can change it to execute in a terminal in a new window and garentee it won't open with a text editor? @stark

Comment: The display manager can launch commands in a terminal, but it is not standardized for different DMs.

Comment: "I want to execute a command with the terminal in linux". Why? If you are a command-line program, assume you are already in a terminal, just run the executable you want to run, don't run any terminal. If you are a GUI program and you want to run a command-line program and show its output, run the program and show its output in your own window, don't run any terminal. You would need a terminal if you wanted to run an interactive terminal program such as vim.

Comment: Do you just need to run it in the command line (console) or do you need the full windowing system? Most of my linux systems don't have a gui at all.

Comment: I need it running with a new window @NomadMaker . my program's point is to open up a terminal in java if it doesn't exist (double click jar)

Comment: What you're asking is not easy, see if this helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137782/launching-a-terminal-emulator-without-knowing-which-ones-are-installed

Comment: well I could simply scan through the list of terminals and see which ones will not throw an exception to find the default terminal. Also make it configurable. They all seem to start with usr/bin that is pretty helpful. The process may take one second to work and I may need to use multi threading to make it faster but it's possible. I wish java would tell me

Comment: Why should any programming language tell you how to run any specific arbitrary complex program? Java gives you tools to run other programs. The documentation required to explain how to run all other programs would be rather extreme.

Comment: java requires you to input the terminal name for it to open up the window so therefore I need to fetch the terminal name. For other oses they are like here is this hard coded string cmd or bin/bash.

Answer (score 1):

here is a cross platform way to determine the os terminal. supports windows, mac and linux

```
    public static String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
    public static String[] windows_terminals = new String[]
    {
        "cmd",
        "powershell",//seems to freak out and seems to be beta even in 2020 with all it's bugs
    };
    
    public static String[] mac_terminals = new String[]
    {
        "bin/bash"  
    };
    
    public static String[] linux_terminals = new String[]
    {
            "/usr/bin/gcm-calibrate",
            "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal",
            "/usr/bin/mosh-client",
            "/usr/bin/mosh-server",
            "/usr/bin/mrxvt",           
            "/usr/bin/mrxvt-full",        
            "/usr/bin/roxterm",          
            "/usr/bin/rxvt-unicode",        
            "/usr/bin/urxvt",             
            "/usr/bin/urxvtd",
            "/usr/bin/vinagre",
            "/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator",
            "/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal",   
            "/usr/bin/xterm",
            "/usr/bin/aterm",
            "/usr/bin/guake",
            "/usr/bin/Kuake",
            "/usr/bin/rxvt",
            "/usr/bin/rxvt-unicode",
            "/usr/bin/Terminator",
            "/usr/bin/Terminology",
            "/usr/bin/tilda",
            "/usr/bin/wterm",
            "/usr/bin/Yakuake",
            "/usr/bin/Eterm",
            "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper",
            "/usr/bin/koi8rxterm",
            "/usr/bin/konsole",
            "/usr/bin/lxterm",
            "/usr/bin/mlterm",
            "/usr/bin/mrxvt-full",
            "/usr/bin/roxterm",
            "/usr/bin/rxvt-xpm",
            "/usr/bin/rxvt-xterm",
            "/usr/bin/urxvt",
            "/usr/bin/uxterm",
            "/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper",
            "/usr/bin/xterm",
            "/usr/bin/xvt"
    };
    
    public static String getTerminal()
    {
        String[] cmds = getTerminals(osName);
        for(String cmd : cmds)
        {
            try 
            {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd + " cd " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
                return cmd;
            } 
            catch (Throwable e) {}
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String[] getTerminals(String os)
    {
        return os.contains("windows") ? windows_terminals : os.contains("mac") ? mac_terminals : os.contains("linux") ? linux_terminals : null;
    }
```