# How to get Linux Terminal name

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, subprocess

Let's say I wanted to run another terminal outside of my script. I would first do:

```py
from subprocess import Popen
```

then I would call:

```py
Popen(['xterm (or insert terminal name here)', '-e', 'xterm'])
```

That is all fine, but I want to know if there is a way to find the terminal name that the user is running the Python script from (the terminal that the user typed in `./python_application_name_here.py`), let's say that variable was called `x` .

Is there a way that I could do this?:

```py
Popen([str(x), '-e', str(x)])
```

I found a way to do this in Java, but I don't know the language very well: [how to get the linux terminal name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65036960/how-to-get-the-linux-terminal-name)

Comment: That question isn't getting the terminal the user is using, it's just returning whichever terminal is installed on the user's system. If there are multiple terminals installed, it will return the first one in the array.

Comment: On MacOS, the environment variable `TERM_PROGRAM` contains the name of the terminal application. I don't know if this is also true on other operating systems.

Comment: What if the user is connected via ssh, or an actual hardware terminal hooked up via a serial line?

Comment: After digging for a long time I found out that on Linux that environment variable is called TERM. so now what I can basically do now is ```'env' >> whatever.txt```  and then just ```open()``` it in python and look for the variable name TERM. Thanks @Barmar for your suggestion.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate, with limited usefulness: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481142/launch-default-terminal-emulator-by-command Between the lines, it's telling you that on Debian (and thus Ubuntu, Mint, etc) the command `x-terminal-emulator` will start the admin's (though perhaps not the user's; and this is obscure, so many admins will just have left the default) preferred graphical terminal.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve anyway? There are many situations where you legitimately want to open a terminal window; but there are also many situations where beginner programmers think the users want this when they don't, and wreck an otherwise useful program by creating a horrible usability problem.

Comment: @MaxWerner `TERM` isn't the terminal program, it's the name of the terminal type that it emulates, e.g. `vt100`.

Answer (score -1):

I have not found a way for python yet, but, in bash you can redirect the output of `'env'` to a text file like this: `'env' >> t.txt` and then `open()` it in python. Then use the environment variable to open another terminal:

```py
from subprocess import Popen

with open('dir_name_of_txt.txt', 'r') as var:
   a=var.read().splitlines()
   for rand in a:
       if a[rand].find('TERM=') == int(-1):
           del a[rand]
a = str(a)
if a.find('xterm') != int(-1):
    Popen(['xterm', '-e', 'xterm'])
else:
    if a.find('-256color') != int(-1):#found this happens with xterm
        a.replace('-256color', '')
    Popen([str(a.replace('TERM=', '')), '-e', str(a.replace('TERM=', ''))])
input('it ran! enter to exit')
```

I don't know if this works since I haven't tested it.

Comment: Btw, if any one has a way of doing this in python (preferably without any external text files) please leave an answer this is just a temporary solution that is kind of  "jerry rigged".

Comment: You can also get the environment variables with `os.environ`. (Something like `os.environ["TERM"]`)

Comment: `TERM` indicates what terminal *emulation* the user is running under. A large number of users who are **not** using `xterm` and don't even necessarily have it available on their system will have `TERM=xterm`; other common values are `vt100`, `vt220` etc which are not even names of executables.

Comment: Right. I'm using MacOS Terminal on my computer, but `TERM=xterm-color`.